# Can pydantic do polymorphic JSON serialization based on a field like _type?

Tags: jackson, polymorphism, pydantic, json-serialization

JDK Jackson has JsonSubTypes which can be based on a field like _type or @type or type etc. In our case we are using _operation. This field is absent from the fields of the deserialized object as it represents the type itself.

Is this possible with pydantic, and how?

Comment: I think you are looking for "discriminated unions", see https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions.